# synchronizing files with server using git

Tags: git

Git newbie here. Is there a way to synchronize two repositories, so that the current checked out files will be the latest version of all the changes?

What I have is this:

```
Desktop       Server
-------       ------
Change_X      Change_Y
```

And I would like to enter some "magic" command, and then the changes are merged

```
Desktop       Server
-------       ------
Change_X      Change_X
Change_Y      Change_Y
```

One of the problems is that the desktop is a Windows machine behind a NAT, and I would like to avoid having to set up sshd on it. Basically I would like to do it all using ssh from the desktop to the server.

This seems like it should be trivial to do with git, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

(I thought `git push` would do the trick, but it turns out it doesn't make changes to currently checked-out branches, so the changes from the desktop don't get to the server)

Is there a way to do this with git, or am I off the track?

**Solution:** I downloaded the post-update script from [here](http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update) and put it in the hooks directory on the server, and now `git push` causes the server to update with the changes. So basically the "magic command" resolves to:

```
git pull server:scripts/ master
git push server:scripts/
```

(`scripts` is the folder I'm synchronizing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be possible to create a post-commit hook that will update server's working copy on change (I did exactly the same with mercurial, so i assume it would be possible with git too). so after you push, working copy will be updated automatically.

create post-commit hook that will run `git up` or whatever equivalent command for git is.
i'm sorry i don't know what else to say.
**upd**: there is some explanation in [official git faq](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#head-b96f48bc9c925074be9f95c0fce69bcece5f6e73).

Answer (score 1):

> *One of the problems is that the desktop is a Windows machine behind a NAT, and I would like to avoid having to set up sshd on it. Basically I would like to do it all using ssh from the desktop to the server.*

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you're behind a NAT, the easier thing to do is to run a reverse SSH tunnel using Putty or something, instead of an sshd server.

```
ssh -R3333:127.0.0.1:9418 <user>@<server>
```

Now, connections to `<server>`'s port 3333 will be forwarded to your NAT-ed machine's git port.